# How do I get default LXC iptable rules into Shorewall?

Tags: iptables, shorewall

I'm setting up a server which will be hosting multiple LXC containers. However, starting Shorewall results in loss network access from within the LXC containers.

If I reboot the LXC host and leaves Shorewall in a stopped state, LXC containers works fine. So, I compared the state of iptables at system startup and after a `shorewall start; shorewall stop`.

There is a difference, and I'd like to tell Shorewall about this difference. How do I get the below iptables state into Shorewall for both running and stopped state?

I've been experimenting with `/etc/shorewall/stoppedstate`, but I can't really figure out how to get Shorewall to populate the INPUT chain through `/etc/shorewall/stoppedstate`.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 14730 packets, 1131K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxcbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
    8   498 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxcbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  lxcbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
    1   328 ACCEPT     udp  --  lxcbr0 any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
```

Comment: I've the same problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: As a workaround you can just restart the lxc-net service after restarting shorewall.